# can ObservableField be used to send data between activity and a service?

Tags: android, service, observable, foreground

I want to do some operations in a foreground service. So this service must update some data which need to be reflected to the activity / screen as well. Is it possible to keep an ObservableField as member of the service and pass it to service when it is created. So that i dont have to listen to updates from the service. Can i pass ObservableField as an extra in the intent

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass the `ObservableField` as an intent extra.

If your `Service` is running in the same process as your `Activity`, you can implement an `IBinder` which holds and provides a reference to the `ObservableField`.

Or you use a binding with a `Messenger` and send the observable field as a `msg.obj`. But in this case you could also send the the update directly as a `Message` and apply it on the activity site.